# package suggetions for tracking simple object/marker?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 3d-object-recognition, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to determine the 3D movement (instantaneous pose) of a simple object, e.g., a green tennis ball in a 2x2x2 meter space using a realsense D435 camera. I read the similar questions in the forum and found for example find_object_3d, tod, vr4, but based on the answers i could not conclude which would provide the best results.

The realsense is placed ~1.5meters from the workspace (that should be recorded), and i highly suspect that it will provide quite unreliable results, especially if the tennis ball is 3 meters far from the camera..

Could you recommend what setup/solution/package should be used for the aforementioned problem?

So the pose of a simple green colored marker is required to be determined. Maybe OpenCV-based method suits for this task?

Thank you for the help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324955/package-suggetions-for-tracking-simple-object/marker?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe this package can give you initial start... it is not mine, https://github.com/dovanhuong/object_detection_2d

---

Originally posted by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) with karma: 80 on 2019-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-06-10**:
Thank you, it works as i expected.